# Select Rows as Columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have following table:

```
id  configname      value
--------------------------------------
1   set_count       3         
2   pass_ratio      2         
3   min_right_count     1         
.
.
.
```

I need to create select query which gives result in this manner:

```
set_one_count   pass_ratio  min_right_count
--------------------------------------------------------
3                    2               1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Edit** Check this out for more [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fde3c/3)

```
select set_ratio,pass_ratio,min_right_count
from
(
  select configname,value
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for configname in (set_ratio,pass_ratio,min_right_count)
) piv;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbb7e/1)

```
select 
sum(case when configname='set_count' then 1 else 0 end) as set_one_count,
sum(case when configname='pass_ratio' then 1 else 0 end) as set_one_count,
sum(case when configname='min_right_count' then 1 else 0 end) as min_right_count
from tablename;
```